# Batch Capture incoming ICMP IP as variable

Tags: batch-file, ip, capture, icmp, netstat

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way I can capture incoming ip addresses displayed from 'netstat' command as workable variables.

I'm trying to make a script that waits for a ping from a specific host. Is there any way of capturing this information into workable variable that can be used in a script?

I have piped the output to a log without issue, but I still don't understand any way to go about retrieving the IP's from the text file into workable variables.

Is this even possible with a simple batch file or should I be looking elsewhere?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about showing us what you want to capture, what the output looks like that you want to capture it from and what platform you use?

Comment: The only ICMP information shown in `netstat` are the statistics of the protocol. No addresses.